# I need to model a population where every component have a fixed life span.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I have a certain population, which growth is function of a certain factor.
I have already modeled the growth. Now I need to impose that every individual in the population have a fixed life length.
Can you help me modeling this?

---

Example, because people say "this is unclear".

Growh_rate=f(t)

Death_rate=?? <---I have to model an equation for this.

Life span=X

Population(t) = integral(from 0 to t)(Growh_rate)-integral(from 0 to t)(Death_rate)

---

Please if you can't directly answer the question, can you link me a directory of different models among different themes (population, financial, virus spread, etc)?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Now I need to impose that every individual in the population have a fixed life length. Can you help me in this?

Comment: You may find what you are looking for by searching for *Delay Differential Equation*.

Comment: I see Asaf has already erased the tag, but just so you know, model theory is most certainly not what you are asking about.

Comment: Yes Andrè that's probably a good classification, can you give me the solution or some models example that use DDE?

Comment: Death rate $= f(t-X)$?

Comment: exactly, but how can I write that without using computation to remember the function f? I'm askin a mathematical way, the path is trough DDE, but I don't find how. (With computation I can already do it, it's a lot more simple...)